# VS 2017 recompiles all files every time

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build

Visual Studio rebuilds the whole project every time I press **Build > Build Solution (F7)**. Even when the code isn't modified.

It happens on all projects and I can reproduce the "bug" with a blank project. Apparently, it has something to do with **tracking log files**. Here is what you can find in the *Diagnostic* build log output:

```
pch.cpp will be compiled because it was not found in the tracking log. (TaskId:22)
```

Let me show you a complete example of my problem.

First, I create an empty project.
[image]
My **Build and Run** settings are the following.
[image]
The first time I build, I get the following:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SimpleTrackingLogTest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>pch.cpp
1>SimpleTrackingLogTest.cpp
1>SimpleTrackingLogTest.vcxproj -> C:\kmasson\lab\SimpleTrackingLogTest\Debug\SimpleTrackingLogTest.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

And the second time I build, without modifying the code, I get the exact same output.

In the full log located at *`Debug\SolutionName.log`*, you can find why all files were recompiled by searching for *"will be compiled"* using Ctrl+F. There is one line for each source file.

```
Read Tracking Logs: (TaskId:22)
 Debug\SimpleTr.7CB9D8E0.tlog\CL.read.1.tlog (TaskId:22)
 Outputs for ...\SIMPLETRACKINGLOGTEST\SIMPLETRACKINGLOGTEST\PCH.CPP: (TaskId:22)
      ...\SIMPLETRACKINGLOGTEST\SIMPLETRACKINGLOGTEST\DEBUG\PCH.OBJ (TaskId:22)
      ...\SIMPLETRACKINGLOGTEST\SIMPLETRACKINGLOGTEST\DEBUG\SIMPLETRACKINGLOGTEST.PCH (TaskId:22)
 pch.cpp will be compiled because it was not found in the tracking log. (TaskId:22)
```

And **`CL.read.1.tlog`** contains many lines pointing to *Program Files (x86)* and *Windows* but also the 2 following lines (`^` is really in the file):

```
^C:\...\SIMPLETRACKINGLOGTEST\SIMPLETRACKINGLOGTEST\PCH.CPP
... Some .DLL
^C:\...\SIMPLETRACKINGLOGTEST\SIMPLETRACKINGLOGTEST\SIMPLETRACKINGLOGTEST.CPP
... Many .DLL,.NDS, .H..
```

I don't understand why tracking log files aren't working. It happens on a big project I'm working on and it's just unusable, every time I want to build it rebuilds the whole project. Also, it seems that tracking log files are way to small for the big project I'm working on. Like it's not generating what it should.

I searched online about tracking log files but there is only little informations about them. I tried to reinstall completely Visual studio, disabling Windows Defender and deleting my local user *Temp* directory.

If you need any informations about my setup, please ask.

Comment: what is sure is that the full project get recompiled because the precompiled header get recompiled. Why, this is the question, I tested to create a new project and don't get this behaviour. If you don't use precompiled headers, you might deactivate them (Property -> C/C++ -? Precompiled Headers -> Precompile Header Use -> Not Using Precompiled Header).  It may by side effect solve your issue

Comment: @sandwood thanks for trying this. Precompiled Headers doesn't seem to be the problem here. Thought I noticed it has something to do with the project location. I'm trying a few things and I will post the answer if it works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get it working. It has something to do with the project's location. It works on `C:\Users\kmasson` but not in `C:\kmasson`. Though I have read/writting rights and I even tried to run VS as Administrator. I don't understand why it wasn't working but now the issue is fixed.